# Using sampleRegions with randomPoints samples less points than what is provided

Tags: google-earth-engine, random, samplepoints

Link for the code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/89616ca3147334915eca9f3957bb778f

I am using GEE in order to access image, generate random points on top of it and then sample it using the random points.

I have found out unexpected behavior : I generate 200 random points, and then when I  sample the region, I get back only  192 points.
This happens for different numbers of sample points:
(500 random points ->472 sampled
100 random points -> 95 sampled
1000 random points -> 946 sampled
etc...)

```
var smap=ee.ImageCollection('NASA_USDA/HSL/SMAP10KM_soil_moisture').filterBounds(geometry).filterDate('2020-01-01', '2021-01-01').median().clip(geometry);

var randomPoints = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints(
    {region:geometry, points: 1000});
    
var fcPointSamp = smap.sampleRegions({
  collection: randomPoints,
  scale: 10000
});

Map.addLayer(smap,{},'SMAP');

Map.addLayer(randomPoints,{},'random_points')
Map.centerObject(geometry,8)

print('Number of points', randomPoints.size());
print('Number of sampled points', fcPointSamp.size());
```

Why does this happen? Is there any way I can control the number of points that are being sampled?

Link for the code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/89616ca3147334915eca9f3957bb778f

**EDIT:**
based on Daniel's answer: workaround for geemap:

```
dummy_band=img.addBands(ee.Image(-9999).rename('temp')).clip(fc)

img_replaced_masked = img.unmask(dummy_band.select('temp'))

###replace the masked values in img with the -9999 values
img_mask_masked_values = img.unmask(dummy_band.select('temp'))
```

then, when I used sampleRegions, the no value pixels got value of "-9999"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You miss samples because there are areas in `geometry` not covered by `smap`. So, `randomPoints` will contain samples in this area, but not `fcPointSamp`.

A fix to this is to use `stratifiedSample()` instead. It will give you a random sampling, and you will not end up with missing values. Since you don't actually want to stratify on anything, you can create a dummy constant image, and use that band to stratify, so you end up with a single stratum.

```
var fcPointSamp = smap
  .addBands(ee.Image(1).rename('temp')) // Add dummy band
  .stratifiedSample({ 
    numPoints: 1000, 
    classBand: 'temp', // We stratify on the dummy band - a single class
    scale: 1000, // Since your geometry is so small, you cannot fit 1,000 samples with a scale of 10,000
    geometries: true // Just included so it can be put on a map, to highlight that this is random sampling
  });
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/c79d76884a132f92f670a97fc8155023

Comment: thank you for the answer. From your answer I understand that the issue is that I have these "masked" pixels. You code worked great on GEE , however, I wonder if I can change the masked pixels into -9999 (wasn't able to do it but it should be possible no? ) also, my original script is writtenw ith geemap, wonder if you used stratified sample with geemap, couldn't find it there, and I get this error "EEException: Unable to transform geometry into requested projection. also when adding the projection as parameter. Do you know something about it? :)

Comment: just updating that it worked with unmask on geemap , thanks for the help!
adding to the main post